# How to update the xml attribute values using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am passing $SourceFileName as studentpackage.zip and copying the zip to below two location.how to update the xml attribute configsolutionfile when there is a change in $SourceFileName

```
function BuildArchive          
{            
    param            
    (            
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]            
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]             
        [String] $SourceFileName = ""                                                    
    )  
}
```

D:\StudentProgram\Automate\Publishing\Content\Forums\StudentPackage contains an xml file where I need to update the attribute `configsolutionfile`

```
<?xml?>
<config>
  <solutions>
    <configsolutionfile solutionpackagefilename="studentpackage.zip" />
  </solutions>
</config>
```

D:\StudentProgram\Automate\Publishing\Content\Archives\StudentPackage contains an xml file where I need to update the attribute `configsolutionfile`

```
<?xml?>
<config>
  <solutions>
    <configsolutionfile solutionpackagefilename="studentpackage.zip" />
  </solutions>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[xml]$xml_contents = Get-Content 'path to XML'
$xml_contents.config.solutions.configsolutionfile.solutionpackagefilename = 'test'
$xml_contents.Save('Path to new XML')
```